# Passing a value from a selectfield in a view to a store

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

How do i correctly pass the value of my selectfield into the ajax proxy in my store?

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.view.Home',{
extend:'Ext.Panel',
xtype:'home',
config:{
    title:'Home',
    iconCls:'home',
    html:'<h1>Home Page</h1><hr><p>Welcome to Sencha Touch 2 Training</p>',
    layout:'fit',
    scrollable:true,
    styleHtmlContent:true,
    styleHtmlCls:'home',


    items: [
            {
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                id: 'visit',
                label: 'Choose one',
                value:'restaurant',
                options: [
                    {text: 'Museum',  value: 'museum'},
                    {text: 'Pubs', value: 'pub'},
                    {text: 'Attractions',  value: 'attraction'}
                ]
            }
        ]
                }

    })
```

I am trying to place the value here: '+ REFERENCE HERE +' in the code below. I have tried '+#visit+' and '+#value+' with no success

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.store.Places',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',

config:{

    autoLoad:true,
    model:'FirstApp.model.Place',
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?  location=52.247983,-7.141113&radius=10000&types=food&name='+ REFERENCE HERE +'&sensor=false&key=KEY',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'results'
        }
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a component by ID in Sencha frameworks you want to use Ext.getCmp, and then use the getValue method. So where you are trying to put the reference, put this:

```
Ext.getCmp('visit').getValue()
```

Ideally you want to try to stay away from hardcoded component IDs, and instead use refs/selectors based on the component path, type, etc.

Comment: I have tried '+Ext.getCmp('visit').getValue()+'   And from this i get the below error.                                                Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method getValue of undefined